# Loop through radio groups in javascript

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I am trying to loop through Radio groups and validate that the user has made a selection using Javascript.  The radio groups are dynamic so the field names are unknown at runtime, and the number of radio groups will also be unknown. After the user has made a selection for each radio group, then process the form.

Comment: @case "Pure" Javascript, or is Prototype an option?

Comment: @case "Pure" Javascript, or is **jQuery** an option?

Comment: Pure Javascript, but yes jQuery is an option.

Comment: also, what do you mean the fields names will be unknown! can you post some code?

Comment: @ifaour Your sarcasm has been duely noted. ;-)

Comment: @goreSplatter - I was actually surprised, it has been awhile since someone offered help with Prototype..it's either Prototype is so easy so no one is asking Prototype related questions or just (the fact) jQuery is the number 1 JS library.

Comment: @ifaour Yeah, you might say I kinda started out wrong. I went into Prototype instead of going for *the number 1 JS library*. But it's good to know there are dinosaurs around should actual Prototype questions arise ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a map to find the field names that are not checked.

```
function add() {
    remaining[this.name] = true;
}
function remove() {
    delete remaining[this.name];
}
var form = $(this), remaining = {};
form.find(':radio').each(add).filter(':checked').each(remove);
```

Then the `remaining` variable will be an object that holds the names of the radio group that the user hasn't checked.

If it is an empty object, then the user has selected all groups.

For a working example, look here: http://jsfiddle.net/thai/qtJsJ/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could select all radio buttons using the 'input:radio' selector and then make sure that for each distinct name a value is set.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(this).find("input:radio").each(...)
}
```

Comment: I don't know how this is related to the question but whatever you are suggesting should be something like: `$(':radio').each(...)`

Answer (score 0):

with pure javascript you could try something like

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i = 0; i<elements.length; i++)
{
    if(elements[i].type === "radio")
    {
        //dostuff
    }
}
```